# parse.com append retrieving data

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am practicing Parse now, I now how to retrieve data, but the problem is
when I try to save object in parse, my first print(postsArray) doesn't show anything. here is my code.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var postsArray = [PFObject]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()




    fetchData()
    print(postsArray)
    tableView.reloadData()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return postsArray.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("practiceCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel!.text = postsArray[indexPath.row].objectForKey("text") as? String
    return cell



}

func fetchData() {



        //empty postArray
        postsArray = []

        //bring data from parse
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Practice")

        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil && objects != nil{
                for object in objects! {

                    self.postsArray.append(object)
                    print(self.postsArray)
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

print method after I append data, shows proper data, but the first print method in the viewDidLoad() show me nothing. So my tableView doesn't show me anything as well.

I read parse doc and searched other questions, It seems nothing wrong, it is not working.

Would you give me an advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your query is completed, you need to `self.tableView.reloadData()` which will cause the `tableView` to ask it's delegate again how many rows it should have, which will be accurate after the data is returned. Alternatively, you could use a `PFQueryTableViewController` which will handle it's objects by itself and makes it easier for you to manage.